# How to change external class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the SwipeRefreshLayout class from the external appCompat library in my android project. However, when I change values or add a new method to this class I can't see those changes in my project.

I already refreshed and rebuild the project.

Does anyone know how I am able to see the changes I made?

Comment: What do you mean you are changing a `class` ? You cannot add code to classes. You add code to .java files. If you did manage to change the code for `SwipeRefreshLayout`, how are you ensuring that your version gets picked up instead of the one in support V4 ? Are you re-compiling a new supportV4 jar ?

Comment: By changing the class I meant changing the code in the android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.java . Do you know how I can recompile it to see the changes?

Comment: This repository contains the code for [SwipeFreshLayout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java). You could clone that locally and build your own jar. While this answers your question I'm unsure if that is what you really want. Do you need to change the core functionality of SwipeRefreshLayout in some way ?

Comment: Basically I want to change the color value of the CircleImageView inside the SwipeRefreshLayout class which is set private and the method setProgressBarBackground() which is meant to change it doesn't work somehow. So i wanted to try to change the color with my own method and came up to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit support libraries directly in my opinion.

Just create your own class..?

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class MySwipeLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

... // custom methods

@Override
... // SwipeRefreshLayout method to override

}
```

Comment: I tried that already. But I need to get access to some values and no getter methods are implemented for those. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You can use all methods from the superclass. If there are no methods returning the values you need, you could try copy-pasting the whole class in *your* library and change its name, but that's quite a brute way and I don't know what couldn't work.

Comment: Yeah I considered that already but thats quite ugly in my opinion :/

Comment: There's no other way as far as I know. You need to create your own class, either from scratch, either extending one.